# How to properly tokenize strings in C without random symbols?

Tags: arrays, c, string, computer-science, tokenize

I'm currently learning C and trying to write a function to tokenize a paragraph/string delimited by spaces and return an array with all the tokens. I'm stuck because I can't figure out why some token will carry symbols that are not in the original string. Can someone help me figure out what's wrong with my code? Plus I don't want to add additional library into the code or use functions like strtok().

```
char **tokenizeParagraph(char *paragraph) {
    char *ptr = paragraph;
    char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORDLENGTH];
    int wordIndex = 0;
    int wordLen = 0;

    while (*ptr) {
        wordLen = 0;

        while (*ptr && *ptr != ' ') {
            wordLen++;
            ptr++;
        }

        if (wordLen > 0) {
            strncpy(words[wordIndex], paragraph, wordLen);
            printf("%s\n", words[wordIndex]);
            wordIndex++;
        }

        ptr++;
        paragraph = ptr;
    }
    return words;
}
```

Here's a demo result:

```
tokenizeParagraph("I'm currently learning C and trying to write a function to tokenize a paragraph/string delimited by spaces and return an array with all the tokens.");
```

[Error Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yklkk.png)

Much appreciated!

Edited:

The dynamic memory methods @Sourav Kannantha B and @Finxx suggested are very helpful. However since I didn't want to add <stdlib.h> library, I moved the array declaration out of the function and passed it in as a parameter, so the array will not be erased with stack memory after the function returns.

```
char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_CHARS];
void tokenizeParagraph(char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_CHARS], char *paragraph)
```

Comment: well for one thing, the array, words, is allocated on the stack and returning it is undefined behavior.  read up about heap vs stack

Comment: I don't see where you thanks terminate the strings, over and above the other problems that have been diagnosed.

Comment: The use of `strncpy` is a likely source for your bugs. Never use that function. For details see [Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/281518)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Finxx already suggested is good enough. But you can still improve it if wordLen varies very widely.

```
char **tokenizeParagraph(char *paragraph) {
    char *ptr = paragraph;
    char** words = malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAX_WORDS);
    int wordIndex = 0;
    int wordLen;

    while (*ptr) {
        wordLen = 0;

        while (*ptr && *ptr == ' ') {
            ptr++;
        }

        paragraph = ptr;

        while (*ptr && *ptr != ' ') {
            wordLen++;
            ptr++;
        }

        if (wordLen > 0) {
            words[wordIndex] = malloc(sizeof(char) * wordLen+1);
            strncpy(words[wordIndex], paragraph, wordLen);
            words[wordIndex][wordLen] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", words[wordIndex]);
            wordIndex++;
        }
    }

    for(;wordIndex < MAX_WORDS; wordIndex++) {
        words[wordIndex] = NULL;
    }
    return words;
}
```

Also, note that [strncpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) does not add terminating NUL character. This is probably the reason for random characters appearing in the output.

Also, don't forget to `free` the allocated memory from caller function.:

```
int main() {
    ...
    char** words = tokenizeParagraph(para);
    ...
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS; i++) {
        free(words[i]);
    }
    free(words);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked for me now, thanks! I mistakenly thought strncpy() would return a closed string. Also I'll keep in mind of the memory allocation part.

Comment: @LinguaFranca I have edited my code above `return words;`. This part is necessary to avoid dangling pointers, since you are not actually returning 'how many' words are there in `words` array.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the variable `words` on the stack and returning a pointer to this on the stack. However, when you return from the function, the stack is no longer restricted to your program, which means some things your pointer is pointing to may change, causing undefined behavior. In order to prevent this, change this code:

```c
char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORDLENGTH];
```

with this:

```c
char** words = calloc(MAX_WORDS * MAX_WORDLENGTH, sizeof(char));
```

This will allocate memory on the heap instead of the stack, although you need `stdlib.h` to be included.

Comment: I would suggest not to suggest `calloc`. 1. It unnecessarily initializes the data to zero. 2. Using heap allocation when you know the size beforehand is not necessary just to keep the data in memory. 3. You should also mention `free`. 4. There's a simple way passing the array from the calling context.

Comment: Thanks! This information is very helpful.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi 1. It takes care of the null needed to specify the end of the string. 2. The pointer to the stack memory will be dereferenced when you leave the scope of the function. 3. Heap memory is dereferenced when the program exits, and I doubt that holding on to maybe 1KB in memory is really going to hurt anything. 4. If that is actually possible, I will be very intrigued.

Comment: You didn't mention that they needed to call free. And your number 1 is really a bad approach to wotking with strrings in C. I would suggest that you take a look at my SO profile before pointing out things like: Heap memory is deferecend ...